# Acceleration through potential difference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

> Fe^1+ ions are accelerated through a potential difference of V volts.

What does this statement even mean???Please explain it to me.

And please give me a general formula to work out the velocity after the acceleration only based on mass of the ion, its charge and the magnitude of the potential difference.

Comment: Are you familiar what is potential if yes then, qv is nothing but potential energy, when charge released its potential energy will convert into kinetic energy yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The potential difference, or voltage, between two points is the work required, per unit charge, to move the charge between the two points. The units of voltage are joules/coulomb of charge.

One coulomb equals 6.24 x $10^{18}$ elementary charges (protons or electrons).

By the work energy principle, the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy.

From these you should be able to come up with the formula to determine the change in velocity of your ion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Farcher Oops!  Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @Farcher BTW Haven’t you heard? The whole universe is a single electron.